# How to avoid unintended mouse moves in Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, mouse, launcher, icons

My 75 years old mother has big problems in clicking on Unity launcher icons to start applications because she always moves the mouse a bit which prevents the left-click to be accepted. As a work-around I suggested to use Super+Number instead, but I also want her to use her mouse.

Is there a setting to prevent launcher icon rearrangement? This would solve the problem because a left mouse click would start the application even if the mouse would be moved a little bit at the same time when clicking.

Comment: Hi Ralf, just curious, but did you try?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds familiar.

#### Simulated left-click

An elegant solution would be, I think, to make her use the mouse, but replace the "real" mouse click by the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I would also add a small delay of 1 second, to make the action "relaxed".

#### How to set up

Setup is simple:

1. Install `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Add the shortut key: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 1 && xdotool click 1"
   ```

   to the key shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Now she can simply move the mouse to whatever she wants to click, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to click.

(I posted this answer with the simulated click :) )